# Is there a way to check a password for a set of conditions in c++?

Tags: passwords

I'm trying to write a program for a log in system I coded. Basically the user enters a username and password to register and then can login. What I'm trying to do is to check the password for a set of conditions. Those are things like this password has to include more than 8 characters, has to include a capital, has to include a number, etc... . But I don't know how to do it. (I'm relatively new to c++, I only know the basics, and I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community) Thanks <3

Comment: If you decide on how a valid password should look, then it should not be that hard to verify that it meet these restrictions? Check the length of the entered password, check the first character in the string and make sure it is capital and so on?

Answer (score 0):

> more than 8 characters, has to include a capital, has to include a number

I’m assuming you have stored the password in a string, here are some examples:

```
using namespace std;
string input = “passWo1d!”;
int i, len = input.length();
bool long = false;
If (n > 8) { long = true; }
bool u = false, n = false;
bool l = false, s = false;
string c = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (isupper(input[i])) { u = true; }
  if (isdigit(input[i])) { n = true; }
  if (islower(input[i])) { l = true; }
  size_t stmp = input.find_first_not_of(c);
  if (stmp != string::npos) { s = true; }
}
```